# nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, sequence

EDIT:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="getOLTsByProcessStateAndAssignee",query="select o from Olt o where o.activityProcessId IN(:procId) order by modifiedtime desc"),
    @NamedQuery(name="getOLTsByProcessStateAndAssigneeForSearch",query="select o from Olt o where o.activityProcessId IN(:procId) and o.name like :name order by modifiedtime desc"),
    @NamedQuery(name="findOltbyname",query="select o from Olt o where o.name=:oltname and o.jioCenter.id=:jioCenterId"),
 })
@XmlRootElement(name="Olt") @Audited @Entity
@Table(name="olt")
public class Olt extends BaseEntity implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    /*@GeneratedValue(generator="olt_id_gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "olt_id_gen",
        strategy = "com.inn.fttx.model.IntegerSequenceGenerator",
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(name="sequence" , value="OLT_ID_SEQ")
        })
    @Id  */



    @SequenceGenerator(name = "olt_id_SEQ", sequenceName = "olt_id_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="olt_id_SEQ")
```

here I am getting the following exception -

nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

I have seen different threads of coderanch and stackoverflow, what i found:

1. the Oracle database is running (Most likely)
2. you app is connected to it (Most likely)
3. You are connected to the correct database (Maybe/Maybe not)
4. There is actually a sequence table called "olt_id_SEQ"

I just pasted this points above, so i can show what I have done already.

But in my Oracle database, I have this sequence and i can perform select with `nextval` on it.

Please let me know, if trouble is from database side or java? Any suggestion/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Never mind other problems on other posts, what specific problem do you have? I don't see a question in your post.

Comment: Are you sure your sequence exists in the DB schema your application is using?

Comment: @JamesB yes it is there. i have also recreated it. But still getting the same exception. I have also performed select CUSTOMER_ID_sequence.nextval which giving me correct result.

Comment: As stated below, you may need to check the grants on this sequence if the application is using a different schema to the owner of the sequence.

Comment: See answer below from Jorge Campos. I did not take your original post literally. You have to change the sequence name in your code to customer_id_sequence.

Comment: wait let me edit my question again to clear the problem.

Comment: Please run the following against your database: select sequence_owner from all_sequences where sequence_name = 'olt_id_SEQ'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your statement `There is actually a sequence table called "CUSTOMER_ID_sequence"` makes no sense since your code is trying to reach the `olt_id_SEQ` sequence. And a sequence is not a table.

So there are two options here:

1 - The user you are using to connect to oracle does not have proper grants on that sequence `olt_id_SEQ`.

2 - You are using a wrong sequence in your code, since you mentioned it should be

```
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "CUSTOMER_ID_sequence", 
                    sequenceName = "CUSTOMER_ID_sequence", allocationSize=1)
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
                 generator="CUSTOMER_ID_sequence")
```

**Edit**

The OP edited his question but the problem here still are the same as I mentioned above.

1 - The user you are using to connect to oracle does not have proper grants on that sequence `olt_id_SEQ` or this sequence doesn't exists at all. To check that get the **user** and **password** that you use on your application and run this query:

```
select * from all_objects where object_name = 'OLT_ID_SEQ'
```

If this query do not return any row the sequence does not exist or it doesn't have a grant to it.

See what was the schema that is the owner of the sequence. If you are using an user that has limited permission you may need to use: [schemaName].olt_id_SEQ or create a public synonim to this sequence.

Comment: 4 points i mentioned was from other site. And CUSTOMER_ID_sequence was just an example. Actually I am using olt_id_SEQ sequence and using the same in code too. And I have the same sequence in my db too. And I have to tried grant also.

Comment: I thought customer_id_sequence was just an example of the problem but it turns out this is the sequence in use and the code is not referring to it.

Comment: @Aamir, you need to be careful how you post, it is very confusing. Look at the comments above: You stated you ran the statement "select CUSTOMER_ID_sequence.nextval" against your database and it was successful. Now you are saying it is just an example name.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved now. Hibernate was using a sequence automatically. So I provided the grant to that sequence now its working.

Comment: You should accept the answer I provided because it stated this problem about the grant and it was in fact your problem.